# Using YML file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, yaml

I have a YML file with a list of data, I would like to include the data in my laravel project but have no idea how. I am familiar with the symfony way using 'sfconfig'. But after a quick bit of research I am unable to even echo the yml data out in to my laravel view. In the end I would like to loop through the data and generate a usuable array

YML file data

```
ACT:
  city: Canberra
  regions:
    -
      key: Canberra
      name: Canberra
      slug: canberra
```

etc...

I am using Laravel 5, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use [`yaml_parse_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file.php) ?

First write `extension=yaml.so` without any quotes in your php.ini file.

And then:

```
$data = yaml_parse($yaml_file);
print_r($data);
```

`$data` is an array through which you can easily iterate!

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it provides me with an error, "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controller\yaml_parse() " I found this strange since it is a a built in php function

sorry about the late reply btw

Comment: @seus write extension=yaml.so without any quotes in your php.ini files.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it really helped :), please edit your answer to include the 'extension=yaml.so" as the first instruction

Answer (score 2):

Laravel internally uses the Symfony YAML component, so it's available for use readily in your project without adding any PHP extensions. Simply `use` it and call it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

...

print_r(Yaml::parse('a: b'));
```